# C# HttpClient Request HTTPS Exception error

Tags: c#, exception, https, httpclient

I am getting an intermittent error with a MVC Web App on the .NET Core 2.2 that sends Http requests to get information from various APIs.

I believe the error is related to the URI being a https instead of a http as other calls to other APIs without the https work absolutely fine. Even with the Client Handler defining the certificate and protocol settings I still get this exception error every now and again:

> An error occurred while sending the request.
>
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>    at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>    at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
>    at tf.PriceService.Core.Classes.WilliamHillMatching.GetHorsesFromEvent(String eventid) in C:\agent\_work\9\s\src\tf.PriceService.Core\Classes\WilliamHillMatching.cs:line 316
>    at tf.PriceService.Core.Classes.WilliamHillMatching.getPrices(List`1 whCompetitions, Race tfRaceData) in C:\agent_work\9\s\src\tf.PriceService.Core\Classes\WilliamHillMatching.cs:line 94
>    at tf.PriceService.Core.Services.PriceService.<>c__DisplayClass50_0.<b__3>d.MoveNext() in C:\agent_work\9\s\src\tf.PriceService.Core\Services\PriceService.cs:line 173
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at tf.PriceService.Core.Services.PriceService.getBookmakerRacePrices(DateTime workDate, List`1 tfPriceList, Race tfRaceData) in C:\agent_work\9\s\src\tf.PriceService.Core\Services\PriceService.cs:line 178
>    at tf.PriceService.Core.Services.PriceService.processRacePrices(Object state) in C:\agent_work\9\s\src\tf.PriceService.Core\Services\PriceService.cs:line 341

Here is the code:

```
    public static async Task<WilliamHillData.Market> GetHorsesFromEvent(string eventid)
    {
        string res = "";

        using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler())
        {
            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls;

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("apiKey", "key");

                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://gw.whapi.com/v2/sportsdata/events/" + eventid + "/?&includeAllDescendants=true"))
                {
                    res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
        }

        JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(res);
        List<WilliamHillData.Market> list = jobject["markets"].ToObject<List<WilliamHillData.Market>>().ToList();
        list[0].eventid = eventid;

        return list[0];
    }
```

It seems to point out this specific part:

```
 using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://gw.whapi.com/v2/sportsdata/events/" + eventid + "/?&includeAllDescendants=true"))
                {
                    res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
```

Am I missing something from my Http request? Is there an alternative way?

Comment: Can you isolate the HTTPS call only and try that? HttpClient will not close sockets quick enough, use IHttpClientFactory. Let us know how you get along with the factory and then isolate the call to make sure its that which is always throwing an error. As you wrote intermittent error i would point to HttpClient as being the issue at the moment.

Comment: I am calling alot of HttpRequests to other API urls too. They're in loops so there are many other requests aswell. I am going to create one instance of HttpClient and reuse it instead of creating a new instance each time and see how it goes.

Comment: Even creating an isolated HttpClient will still create the same issue, you really need to use IHttpClientFactory, it reuses threads more efficiently and clears down the sockets. It's not difficult to use. Isolate this call to the Https uri and see if thats your issue. If not its the HttpClient.